# What percentage of Android devices have BLE support?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-le

Just asking for a bit of data, as I couldn't find it anywhere. Useful to know whether to develop for BLE or Bluetooth. How about percentage over time as well?

Answer (score 0):

Android has started supporting BLE from version 4.3 onwards. I guess all the android phones that now comes with Android 4.3 or above out of the box will be having BLE support in both hardware and software. Decide on which technology to use based on your application! If its some control application, and you don't have any end user who is still on devices that has stopped android updates beyond 4.0, go for BLE else BT classic will be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's my suspicion that the software is implemented to allow manufacturers to ship BLE hardware, but that most devices don't actually have the BLE hardware. That's what I was trying to discover with this question.